# Lagging scrolling problem on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to optimize UICollectionView loading. I have array which is have 40 images in there and it's lagging while scrolling. I researched a lot but I couldn't find a proper solution for local images async. I tried  DispatchQueue global async but it's not working great. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Here is the my problem:

[lagging scroll problem gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW64H.gif)

Here is my CollectionView swift file:

```
    extension ThemesVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return ThemeManager().themeBackgroundImages().count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ThemesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ThemesCollectionViewCell
        
        cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        
        cell.themeCellImageView.image = ThemeManager().themeBackgroundImages()[indexPath.row]
        
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width/2.34, height: view.frame.size.height * 0.3)
    }
}
```

UICollectionViewCell Swift file:

```
import UIKit

class ThemesCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var themeCellImageView: UIImageView!
}
```

Here is the ThemeManager().themeBackgroundImages() codes:

```
func themeBackgroundImages() -> [UIImage]{
    var images = [UIImage]()
    images.reserveCapacity(40)

    images = [UIImage(named: "original-theme")!, UIImage(named: "blue-theme")!, UIImage(named: "purple-theme")!, UIImage(named: "pink-theme")!, UIImage(named: "red-theme")!, FlyTheme().backgroundImage, DreamTheme().backgroundImage, LoverTheme().backgroundImage, NatureTheme().backgroundImage, InspireTheme().backgroundImage, TimeMachineTheme().backgroundImage, NowhereTheme().backgroundImage, DarkThoughtsTheme().backgroundImage, FutureCityTheme().backgroundImage, LostTheme().backgroundImage, FireTheme().backgroundImage, PatternTheme().backgroundImage, HorizonTheme().backgroundImage, SpelTheme().backgroundImage, WonderlandTheme().backgroundImage, BreatheTheme().backgroundImage, PassionTheme().backgroundImage, TimelapseTheme().backgroundImage, FugitiveTheme().backgroundImage, InfiniteWayTheme().backgroundImage, LonelyTheme().backgroundImage, RelationshipTheme().backgroundImage, MoonlightTheme().backgroundImage, DreamlandTheme().backgroundImage, WayOutTheme().backgroundImage, MistyTheme().backgroundImage, UnpredictableTheme().backgroundImage, VolcanoTheme().backgroundImage, DiscoverTheme().backgroundImage, PurpleInspirationTheme().backgroundImage, ForestTheme().backgroundImage, RainbowTheme().backgroundImage, FlowersTheme().backgroundImage, TheMoonTheme().backgroundImage, LuridTheme().backgroundImage]
    
    return images
}
```

Comment: What is the implementation of ThemeManager.themeBackgroundImages() method, could you please add its implementation to the question?

Comment: Also, a few observations that don't necessarily impact the performance but may improve your code:
1. Don't use `qos: .background` for work that prepares data to be displayed on screen while the user is awaiting it. Better use `.userInitiated` for that.
2. No need to call `cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 20` every time you dequeue a cell, better move that to the `awakeFromNib` method of the cell class.
3. Instead of `cell.self.themeCellImageView.image` you can just write `cell.themeCellImageView.image`.

Comment: Another tip: you might want to use Time Profiler instrument to profile your app while scrolling. It will provide you a breakdown of which methods are being called, which of them take the most time and will show the heaviest stack trace that is usually a candidate to be optimized first.

Comment: The ThemeManager.themeBackgroundImages() method func returns an array with 40 images in it. Thank you for your other suggestions.

Comment: @ataberkturan - very unusual approach. Are you downloading the images "on-the-fly"? Or are they stored locally (in you assets)? Post the relevant code from `ThemeManager().themeBackgroundImages()` ... the way you're calling that is almost certainly contributing to the issue.

Comment: @DonMag I am storing images locally in my assets. ThemeManager().themeBackgroundImages() this function just calling an Array.

Comment: @DonMag I edited the question. You can see the `ThemeManager().themeBackgroundImages()` codes.

Comment: @ataberkturan - I'd have to run some testing to be sure, but it looks like you're needlessly destroying / re-creating your images array every time `cellForItemAt` is called. Try doing it like this: https://pastebin.com/qxKqKtBM  and see if you get better results.

Comment: @DonMag I tried your solution but it didn't work.

Comment: @ataberkturan - are these **large** images? or are they "thumbnails" (that is, already scaled to the size to be displayed)?

Comment: @DonMag yeah they are large images. I am using aspectFill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code that are causing hitches:

1. Every time the collection view needs a cell, your code loads 40 large images from disk, picks one of them, then discards the rest.
2. Even if you'd load just one image per cell, it still happens on the main queue. While the image is being loaded, the UI freezes.
3. The images themselves are very large, so `UIImageView` has to resize them each time it needs to display an image.

To mitigate that, here are my recommendations:

1. Do not create a `ThemeManager` class in `collectionView(:cellForItemAt:)`. Instead, make it a property of the view controller.
2. Instead of having `ThemeManager` return all images at once, make it fetch just one image with a particular index.
3. Make image loading asynchronous, moving the work off the main queue.
4. After loading an image from disk, resize it appropriately so that `UIImageView` wouldn't have to deal with huge resolutions.
5. Implement an image cache of resized images inside `ThemeManager` so that the previously images would load instantly. `NSCache` is a great class that can achieve this.

Here's a example where I marked the implementations of each of the recommendations above:

```swift
import UIKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    // Recommendation #1: make ThemeManager a property
    // instead of recreating it each time
    private let themeManager = ThemeManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(UICollectionViewFlowLayout(), animated: false)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        themeManager.imageKeys.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ThemesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? ThemesCollectionViewCell else {
            fatalError("Unexpected cell class dequeued")
        }
        
        cell.currentIndexPath = indexPath
        
        let cellSize = self.collectionView(collectionView, layout: collectionView.collectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: indexPath)
        themeManager.fetchImage(atIndex: indexPath.item, resizedTo: cellSize) { [weak cell] image, itemIndex in
            guard let cell = cell, let image = image else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let cellIndexPath = cell.currentIndexPath, cellIndexPath.item == itemIndex else {
                    print("⚠️ Discarding fetched image for item \(itemIndex) because the cell is no longer being used for that index path")
                    return
                }
                print("Fetched image for \(indexPath) of size \(image.size) and scale \(image.scale)")
                cell.imageView.image = image
                cell.textLabel.text = "\(indexPath)"
            }
        }
        
        return cell
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let sectionInsets = self.collectionView(collectionView, layout: collectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt: indexPath.section)
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width - sectionInsets.left - sectionInsets.right, height: 128)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        0
    }
}

// MARK: - ThemesCollectionViewCell

final class ThemesCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    var currentIndexPath: IndexPath?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        layer.cornerRadius = 20
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        imageView.image = nil
        currentIndexPath = nil
    }
}

// MARK: - ThemeManager

final class ThemeManager {
    // Recommendation #5: Implement an image cache of resized images inside `ThemeManager`
    private let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
    
    private(set) var imageKeys: [NSString]
    
    init() {
        imageKeys = []
        for i in 1...40 {
            imageKeys.append(NSString(string: "image\(i)"))
        }
    }
    
    // Recommendation #2: make ThemeManager fetch just one image with a particular index.
    func fetchImage(atIndex index: Int, resizedTo size: CGSize, completion: @escaping (UIImage?, Int) -> Void) {
        guard 0 <= index, index < imageKeys.count else {
            assertionFailure("Image with invalid index requested")
            completion(nil, index)
            return
        }
        
        let imageKey = imageKeys[index]
         
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: imageKey) {
            completion(cachedImage, index)
            return
        }
        
        // Recommendation #3: Make image loading asynchronous, moving the work off the main queue.
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {
                completion(nil, index)
                return
            }
            guard let image = UIImage(named: String(imageKey)) else {
                assertionFailure("Image is missing from the asset catalog")
                completion(nil, index)
                return
            }
            
            // Recommendation #4: After loading an image from disk, resize it appropriately
            let resizedImage = image.resized(to: size)
            
            self.imageCache.setObject(resizedImage, forKey: imageKey)
            completion(resizedImage, index)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Image Resize Extension

extension UIImage {
    func resized(to targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let widthRatio  = (targetSize.width  / size.width)
        let heightRatio = (targetSize.height / size.height)
        let effectiveRatio = max(widthRatio, heightRatio)
        let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * effectiveRatio, height: size.height * effectiveRatio)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize)
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0)
        self.draw(in: rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return newImage!
    }
}
```

I've put the whole [sample project on Github](https://github.com/vadimbelyaev/ImagesCache), feel free to clone it and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a native api to achieve lazy loading with large image size

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ThemesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ThemesCollectionViewCell
        
        cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        let image = ThemeManager().themeBackgroundImages()[indexPath.row]

        //Prepare 
        image?.prepareForDisplay { [weak self] preparedImage in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               cell.themeCellImageView.image = preparedImage
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Even you can achieve this by Task

```
let image = UIImage(named: "big-image")

Task {
   imageView.image = await image?.byPreparingForDisplay()
}
```